# Get id from table row in ajax by clicking button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get value ( id ) from my row in table.
This is my row

```
 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
```

There is my button to delete

```
<button type='button' id='btn-delete' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete' style='margin-left: 15px;'><i class='ti-trash'></i>
```

and there is Jquery/Ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-delete', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete_record.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id:id},
     success:function(data){
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      location.reload();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
```

in my `id` I got "btn-delete" instead for example 1 when I am choosing first row or 2 when second.

I want to post ID to my php file where I am deleting record from DB

Edit:
Table rows

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td id=".$row['id'].">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['pswd'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-success btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal'><i class='ti-pencil'></i>
                        <button type='button' id='btn-delete' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' style='margin-left: 15px;'><i class='ti-trash'></i>
                        </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        }
```

Comment: What isn't working the way you want it to? and is this a mysql related question?

Comment: I am getting value of id - btn-delete instead of id of row like 1 , 2 etc..

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique. You should be using a class instead.

Comment: I used answer from @Colby Borean, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `$(this)` is your actual button. That is why you are getting 'btn-delete' when you request the id.

What you could do if you have one button for every row is apply an html data attribute to the button similar to `<button data-id=".$row['id']."></button>`.

Then on your button click to get this data attribute value you could write

```
id = $(this).data("id")
```

Comment: @Defus glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get `$(this).attr("id")` so you need to set this id from PHP first. Currently you are not setting it in `echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";`

You should set this id explicitly.

`echo "<td id=".$row['id'].">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";`

Comment: I did it and now my ID got value btn-delete

Comment: sure, because you are trying to get id from this, which in your context is button

Comment: show where your button is placed, and I will help you. I mean if this button is inside <tr>?